# How to move a rectangle in chess game

Tags: xna, move, rectangles, chess

I am programming Chess and wanted to know how I can change the spot of my rectangles. If you need any more informations let me know in the answers. I would be really happy if I could get any answers that could help me. Thanks.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 0):

A rectangle has an int `x` and `y` component. They represent the position on the screen. `x: 0, y: 0` represents the upper left corner of the screen. They're measured in pixels.

Example(assumingly in Game class)

```
Rectangle chessPiece1;
// in init function:
chessPiece1.x = 100;
```

You'll see that the chess piece has moved 100 pixels to the right on the screen(if you've drawed of course).

```
// if you put this in the update function, your chess piece will move 1 pixel to the right every time the update function is called!
chessPiece.x++;
```

And you can do this in the `y` direction too.

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle.aspx). 
Also: I assume you are new to stackoverflow, people can be a little harsh if you ask "fix this for me please". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)'s some info on how to make neat questions.

Comment: _"Here's some info on how to make neat questions"_ - is actually pointing to MSDN `Rectangle` class help.  Did you mean to link to SO?  ;)

Comment: @MickyDuncan Oh man I should learn again how to use CTRL C and CTRL V.